# Securing nuget-server with Office 365 authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-web-app-service, nuget-server

I am trying to set up a nuget server for our organization. I am setting it up using the guide at https://www.codeproject.com/articles/872230/create-your-own-private-nuget-server-in-windows-az and all is basically good. The code works and I can access the feed from my browser as well as Visual Studio (2015).

However - we will use it for internal packages as well as letting customers get access to it so we need to secure it and not allow anonymous access.

I have set up authentication to require log on with our organization's Azure Active Directory accounts. It is done using the "built-in" configuration in Azure Portal.

[image]

The "Existing app" was originally generated by the portal using the "Express" way of configuring authentication.

When I access the collection with a browser, I am asked to log in with my company Office 365 account - all is  fine, but when I try to add the nuget service as a "Package Source" in Visual Studio, I am prompted a bit differently:

[image]

It does not accept my credentials when logging in using my corp email and password or with DOMAIN\USER way of doing it.

Also - I am a little bit confused about the login prompt. I would have expected the UI for the log-in would look like the "normal" log in prompt in Visual Studio:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here? How do I secure my nuget feed in Azure with Office 365 authentication ... such that it works in Visual Studio?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

> It does not accept my credentials when logging in using my corp email and password or with DOMAIN\USER way of doing it.

From the screenshot that you seems want to connect to Azure web app. Please try below steps to see if it helps:

1)  Get publish profile

[image]

2) Open publish profile then find user name and password

[image]

Comment: Hi @jambor - are we misunderstanding each other? I would like to secure the nuget endpoint/App Service with Office365 authentication such that VStudio can access it and prompt the user for O365 credentials. I fail to see how the credentials for the publish profile should help. Also - using the built-in Package Managed service in VSTS causes VStudio to prompt for (Office365) credentials when adding the endpoint as "Package Source". I was hoping I could do the same with my own endpoint. Any thoughts on this? :-)